# SQL Create Table Error - Key is too long?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following SQL command to create a table, but it's giving the me the following error.

`#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes`

I check SQL documentation, and it says that "Message: Specified key was too long; max key length is %d bytes" which didn't quite help.

```
CREATE TABLE Consist_of
(
    dssn    INTEGER,
    pre_no  VARCHAR(255),
    pname   VARCHAR(255),
    trade_name VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (dssn, pre_no) REFERENCES Prescription(dssn, pre_no),
    FOREIGN KEY (pname, trade_name) REFERENCES Drug(pname, trade_name)
);
```

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? (Two different products, with different limitations.)

Comment: Removed the Oracle tag by going through the error!

Answer (score 0):

So as per the error it is clear that you are passing the maximum limit. For MyISAM tables it is 1000 bytes and for InnoDB it is set to 767 bytes.

You can refer to the [resolution of this bug reported](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6604).

Answer (score 0):

This error means that length of index index is more then 1000 bytes. MySQL and storage engines may have this restriction. I have got similar error on MySQL 5.5 - 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes' when ran this script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example_table1 (
  first_col varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  second_col varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  third_col varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  KEY `index` (first_col, second_col, third_col)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

UTF8 is multi-bytes, and key length is calculated in this way - 500 * 3 * 3 = 4500 bytes.

But note, next query works!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example_table1 (
  first_col varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  second_col varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  third_col varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  KEY `index` (first_col, second_col, third_col)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

With a character set of (I assume) utf8, a VARCHAR(255) would need `255 x 3 = 765` bytes for its index.
In your case `(255+255+255) x 3 = 2295` (for each varchar row).

You can increase the maximum InnoDB index prefix size in MySQL 5.6 to 3072 bytes by setting innodb_large_prefix to `YES` along with other settings that you'll also need in order to enable that one, discussed here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix